# How to populate the aspx:Dropdown from c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a following `aspx:dropdown` in `aspx` file:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlbStatus" Width="210px" Height="30px" CssClass="ddlb" 
         runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="ddlbStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" Style="text-align:left">
   <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value="NA"> </asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="New" Value="NEW"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Open" Value="OPEN"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Closed" Value="CLSD"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to populate it from my `c#` file. I tried it with the following code but it didn't work for me:

```
 ddlbStatus.SelectedItem = r["OrderPeriodStatus"].ToString();
```

For example `r["OrderPeriodStatus"].ToString();` prints `NEW or OPEN or CLOSED`

I am newbie in `asp.net`. What i am doing wrong?

### Updated

I have already three text present in `dropdwonlist`. Now what i want , I fetch the status from a `SQL Query`, and that value will be `NEW` `CLOSED` or `OPEN`. So, for example if i get the `CLOSED` value from database then in my HTML page `CLOSED` will be in selected region.

Comment: Do you want to fill the dropdownlist using C#?

Comment: You probably want to look at the DropDownList.DataSource property and .DataBind method. Have a look at the following documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill or populate your `Dropdownlist` in `C#` in this manner

```
ddlbStatus.Items.Add(r["OrderPeriodStatus"]);
```

**EDIT:**

```
ddlbStatus.SelectedIndex = ddlbStatus.Items.IndexOf(ddlbStatus.Items.FindByText(r["OrderPeriodStatus"].ToString()));
```

Comment: It adds another items in dropdown list, but in my case following things will be happen. In current dropdown list three items are there i.e. NEW OPEN CLOSED. Now i get the fields from database which will be equal to three listed item

Comment: @Amit You mean you have three items and you want to add other items from database?

Comment: I think i misunderstood you. Would you please see the updated section in question

Comment: @Amit I now understand what you are trying.Will let you know.

Comment: Thanks ...waiting for your answer

Answer (score 3):

you can try with

```
ddlbStatus.Items.Add("test","test");
```

Or also

```
ListItem li = new ListItem();
li.Text = "NEW";
li.Value = "NEW";
ddlbStatus.items.add(li);
```

Comment: Always remember that if that you will want to clear the list if the code is likely to run multiple times etc, by doing ddlbStatus.Items.Clear()

Comment: is there really an overload for items.Add with two string params??

Comment: @candie What is test and test?

Comment: Just sample, text and your corresponding value

Comment: I think i misunderstood you. Would you please see the updated section

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers you can bind the drop down down list to a datasource that will populate it for you.

```
ddlStatus.DataSoruce = SomeCollection;
ddlStatus.DataValueField = field1;
ddlStatus.DataTextField = field2;
ddlStatus.DataBind();
```